CSS/JS pagination where the number of pages is automatically discovered from a specific folder on the server
I'm quite new to CSS (and unfortunately ignorant of JS) and would like to know if this is possible:
I would like to code script for CSS (or JS/jQuery if someone could help me with it) for the following situation: I have a website where there is a top-level archive page (a table of contents) with links to individual archive pages, and the actual archive pages are in a folder below that on the server. On the individual archive pages, I would like to be able to load a script (currently I'm using an iframe to load a second nav page into the text page) with the navbar for the archives in it, which consists of prev, TOC, and next button images. Here's where it's a bit tricky: I want the pagination to update the prev/next buttons depending on the current filename of the page (it ends in a number, for example (filename) 1001-1014, but then skips to a second set of numbers at the end of the current "chapter," for example (filename) 2001-2022 etc.), so that it always sends the user to the file previous/next in the row, and so that when the user reaches the beginning of the set, the prev button disappears, and when it reaches the end of all sets, the next button disappears.
Ideally, the coding would be able to find how many pages were in the archive folder itself (and how many were in the  (filename) 1001 set, how many in the (filename) 2001 set, etc.), and paginate accordingly, but it would also be fine to have to update the min/max number of pages manually somewhere if that isn't possible.
So... IS it possible to do this with CSS? If not, can someone help me with the javascript (assuming it's even possible with that)? I looked through the answers on this website and found this (https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination), but I'm afraid it might as well be in a foreign language to me. Which I suppose it is.
I do have a friend more versed in CSS/JS who helped me with the following code, but it seems not to work properly if you don't go directly from the ToC to page 1001, and page up from there. He says my plan isn't possible without knowing more JS, at the very least, and possibly not at all, due to some restriction about not being able to number the pages in the archive folder. (The archive ToC is in the same uppermost folder as the index.html page.)
script:
let maxpages = 1014;

if (sessionStorage.getItem("archivenum") < 1001)
   {
   sessionStorage.setItem("archivenum", 1001);
   }


function navUp() {
   window.open('../CC weblog.html', '_parent');
}

function navPrev() {
   let archivenext = sessionStorage.getItem("archivenum");
   if (archivenext > 1001) {
      archivenext--;
      butVis();
      sessionStorage.setItem("archivenum", archivenext);
   }
    var prevfile = "../CC logs/CC log " + archivenext + ".html";
    window.open(prevfile, "_parent");
}

function navNext() {
   let archivenext = sessionStorage.getItem("archivenum");
   if (archivenext < maxpages) {
      archivenext++;
      butVis();
      sessionStorage.setItem("archivenum", archivenext);
    }    
    var nextfile = "../CC logs/CC log " + archivenext + ".html";
    window.open(nextfile, "_parent");
}  
  
function butVis() {
   let archivenext = sessionStorage.getItem("archivenum");
   if (archivenext == 1001) {
      butPrev.setAttribute('style', 'Visibility: hidden');
   }
   else {
      butPrev.setAttribute('style', 'Visibility: visible');
   }

   if (archivenext == maxpages) {
      butNext.setAttribute('style', 'Visibility: hidden');
   } 
   else {
      butNext.setAttribute('style', 'Visibility: visible');
   }
}

window.onload = function() {
   butVis();
}

script on each HTML page:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    let nBody = document.querySelector('body')
    let nIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    nIframe.setAttribute('id', "show-iframe");
    nIframe.style.display = 'none';
    nIframe.style.position = 'absolute';
    nBody.appendChild(nIframe);
  });

script on the archive navbar page:
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav flex">
<img class="nav" src="../CC images/buts/but-back.png" alt="prev" onclick="navPrev()" name="butPrev">

<img class="navArch" src="../CC images/buts/but-up.png" alt="TOC" onclick="navUp(); sessionStorage.clear()">

    <img class="nav" src="../CC images/buts/but-for.png" alt="next" onclick="navNext()" name="butNext">
    </div>
</div>

Any help is MUCH appreciated!

CSS alone cannot handle this as it lacks logic to dynamically determine files or update navigation. For JavaScript, your current approach can work, but it needs refinement.
Thus, I'd use fetch() or server-side scripts to list files in the archive folder dynamically. If that's not feasible, you can manually define maxpages and ranges in JS.
Therefore, for pagination logic:

Use navPrev() and navNext() to decrement or increment page numbers.
Update butVis() to hide/show buttons dynamically.
Ensure sessionStorage stores and retrieves the current page correctly.

If filenames or ranges are complex, consider mapping them in a JavaScript object, e.g.:
const pageMap = [1001, 1002, 1003, 2001, 2002, 2003];
// Use the array index to calculate next/previous pages.

Refine butVis() to handle edge cases by checking the array bounds.

Thank you for your comment! But aren't your 1-2-3 points what the code already does? At the moment, using the current code, if I open a page of the archive directly (locally), the code flips out and thinks it's the first page of the archive, and the pagination goes awry. Would pageMap stop this? Could you explain the fetch() method you would use in this case, please? Thank you!
